# Tableau: Add hyperlink in a table

Tags: tableau-desktop

on Tableau I'm making a table with two fields: order code and the link url to download the invoice like in the picture you can see below.

[image]

If you click on the link (which is different for each row) you can open the browser page to download the invoice so it works.
But I would like to have a something like this

| code |  |
| --- | --- |
| O-3627-4708 | [Download invoice](https://www.google.com) |
| O-9456-4861 | [Download invoice](https://www.google.com) |

So you click on "Download invoice" and it goes on the browser page.
Is it possible?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have had an answer on Tableau forum and it works fine

https://community.tableau.com/s/feed/0D58b0000ACCSr3CQH